# Let a be a positive number. Evaluate the following integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

Let a be a positive number. Evaluate the integrals 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{t^{4} + a^{4}} dt $$ and  $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{2}}{t^{4} + a^{4}} dt $$ by integrating the function $({z^{2} + a^{2}})^{-1}$  in the counterclockwise direction around the boundary of the region  {z : |z| $\leq$ R, 0 $\leq$ Arg z $\leq$ $\frac{\pi}{4}$ }, and taking the limit as R $\to$ ${\infty}$

I know I am supposed to use Cauchy's theorem for a convex region but not sure how to proceed

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705917/using-residues-to-evaluate-an-improper-integral, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305263/improper-integral-in-complex-analysis...

Comment: Since a appears only to the 4th power, the condition that a is positive is unnecessary.  All you need is a$\ne 0$.  a could even be purely imaginary.

Comment: Actually the $a$-parameter is irrelevant and it is enough to compute $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{1+t^4}$ and $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^2\,dt}{1+t^4}$, which are elementary integrals.